# array.includes() doesn't work as I expect, not detecting included elements

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I'm writing it in this function where the array contains arrays of two elements, a username and a score. I want to find the top N usernames by their score, so every time the function is called, I check to see if the username I'm looking at is already in the array.

```
findLargest(array) {
    let largest = this.state.users.toIndexedSeq().get(0);
    let score = 0;
    console.log(array);
    // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
    this.state.users.entrySeq().forEach((element) => {
      console.log([element[1].username, element[1].score]);
      if (array.includes([element[1].username, element[1].score])) {
        console.log(element);
        console.log(array);
        return null;
      }
      if (element[1].score > largest.score) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
        largest = element[1];
        score = element[1].score;
      }
    });
    return [largest.username, score];
  }
```

However, I just get the top scorer N times.

Comment: I can't help you unless you provide examples of input and expected output. Also, you're mixing functional and imperative programming. Consider using `reduce` in stead of `forEach`.

Comment: what type is `array`? Likely the error lies in the usage of [username, score], which creates a new object. comparing that by reference to anything is always bound to fail